# Grails form field always null

Tags: forms, grails

I want to add password confirmation to my project's registration page. But I'm having a problem with value of one of my fields. All the fields are ok but the password2 field, it's the confirmation password and is a transient field of User domain class. Here are my Domain, Controller and View codes

Domain class:

```
class User {
String fullName
String username
String email
String password
String password2

static transients = ['password2']

static constraints = {
    username size: 5..15, blank: false, unique: true
    email email: true, blank: false
    password  blank:false, size:5..15, matches:/[\S]+/, validator:{ val, obj ->
        if (obj.password != obj.password2)
            return 'user.password.dontmatch'
    }
}
}
```

Part of the Controller:

```
        if (request.method == 'POST') {
        // create domain object and assign parameters using data binding
        def u = new User(params)
        if (! u.save()) {
            // validation failed, render registration page again
             flash.error = "error(s) creating user: Value of the confirmation password is: "+u.password2
            //render(view:"/signup",model:[user:user])
            return [user:u]
        } else {
            // validate/save ok, store user in session, redirect to homepage
            session.user = u
            redirect(controller:'home')
            return
        }
    } else if (session.user) {
        // don't allow registration while user is logged in
        redirect(controller:'home')
        return
    }
```

And a part from the View:

```
<div><input class="pretty-input ${hasErrors(bean:user,field:'email','input-error')}" type="email" name="email" value="${user?.email}" ></input><span>— Enter email</span></div>
<div><input class="pretty-input ${hasErrors(bean:user,field:'password','input-error')}" type="password" name="password"></input><span>— Choose a password</span></div>
<div><input class="pretty-input ${hasErrors(bean:user,field:'password2','input-error')}" type="password" name="password2"></input><span>— Repeat the password</span></div>
```

My code works if I remove password's custom validation because password2's value is always null. I why this happens when all other fields works but password2 not.

Comment: In my vision, I don't see password confirmation as a property of User. It is just a form field that happens to be used by the User. I think you should just compare the user's password to the confirmation field like params.password2 == user.password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trasients fields are not bindables by default, thus you cannot pass params to fill it.

You can do this:

```
static constraints = {
    ... your code here
    password2 bindable: true
}
```

But I recommend you to use a command object to validate that condition, it is clever.